# Error in class(x) while creating panel data using plm function

Tags: r, plm

I'm trying to create a Panel data using the plm function for pooling a model from a balanced Panel data that I imported from Excel.

When I run the code I get the following error:

> Error in class(x) <- setdiff(class(x), "pseries") :    invalid to set
>   the class to matrix unless the dimension attribute is of length 2 (was
>   0)

```
library(plm)
library(readxl)
library(tidyr)
library(rJava)
library(xlsx)
library(xlsxjars)

all_met<- read_excel("data.xlsx", sheet = "all_met")
attach(all_met)

Y_all_met <- cbind(methane)
X_all_met <- cbind(gdp, ecogr, trade)

pdata_all_met <- plm.data(all_met, index=c("id","time"))

pooling_all_met <- plm(Y_all_met ~ X_all_met, data=pdata_all_met, model= "pooling")
```

After running the code I was supposed to get summary statistics of a pooled ols regression of my data. Can someone tell me how I can fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1st:**

Avoid `plm.data` and use `pdata.frame` instead:

```
pdata_all_met <- pdata.frame(all_met, index=c("id","time"))
```

If `plm.data` does not give you a deprecation warning, use a newer version of the package.

**2nd (and addressing the question):**

Specify the column names in the formula, not the variables from the global environment if you use the `data` argument of `plm`, i.e., try this:

```
plm(methane ~ gdp + ecogr + trade, data=pdata_all_met, model= "pooling")
```

Answer (score -1):

check in the structure of your data if variables used in the regression are declared as factor, you can do that by typing: `str(all_met)`.

if yes, then you should declare it as double, or as numeric, (try not to use `as.numeric()` function, it could change values in your data).

personally i've changed that by the next specification in the import code:

```
data <- read_csv("C:/Users/Uness/Desktop/Mydata.csv", 
    col_types = cols(variable1 = col_double(), 
        variable2 = col_double()))
View(data)
```

where variable1 and variable2 are the names of the variables I use, make sure you change that if you copy the code ;)